# ¿Como hacer una superposicion en un constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, constraint-layout

bueno lo que pasa lo puedo mostrar en imágenes

**inicio de sesión**

[image: Inicio sesion]

**vista de load**

[image: Load]

se ve claramente el problema que es que el constraint no tiene en cuenta la superposición y puedo enfocar el edittext aunque la vista de load este por encima.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/vsini"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="INICIAR SESIÓN"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nomusu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Nombre usuario"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pasusu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Contraseña"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nomusu"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ingresar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ingresar"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pasusu"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="____________"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/registro"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/registro"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/registro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Registrarse >>"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ingresar"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"  />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <LinearLayout ...>
    </ViewSwitcher>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/load"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#EEEEEE">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/favicon"
            android:contentDescription="load"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el xml de tu vista, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estes en la segunda vista puedes dejar el conjunto de componentes con visibilidad GONE.
Ejemplo:

```
nomusu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Puedes usarlo con un linearlayout o un realativelayout o otros, solo tienes que asignar un id al contenedor  y darle esa propiedad mientras muestras la otra, de esta forma puedes ocultar conjuntos enteros de componentes.

Comment: El OP usa un ConstraintLayout esto no podría solucionar el problema solo escondería la vista.

Comment: Tuve un problema similar, intente deshabilitando el EditText, removiendo el focus, ocultando el teclado, al final termine utilizando este metodo(similar a esta respuesta).
1 - Muestras tu vista principal **vsini** - VISIBLE
2 - Agregas tu loader con visibility GONE
3 - Al hacer click, cambias la visibilidad de cada uno de ellos.